# Using an Association Proxy for a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose that i have a city that has many buildings. I want to create a method in city, that checks whether the city has buildings with specific conditions, like :

```
def has_building?(conditions)
    !self.buildings.where(conditions).empty?
end
```

Which works fine, but contains behaviour that should be contained in the Building model. Is it possible to create an associated method, so that i can transform it to something like :

```
def has_building?(conditions)
    self.buildings.meet_requirements?(conditions)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings do
    def meet_requirements?(conditions)
      self.where(conditions).any?
    end
  end
end
```

**OR**

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.meet_requirements?(conditions)
    self.where(conditions).any?
  end
end
```

Comment: yes,great ! it seems that any? is the key. I was doing the same thing using empty? and of course was getting a Relation error. yeap, that works fine thanx !